# Microsoft's implementation of fileystem::canonical() not working?

Tags: visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 if I try to get the absolute path as:

```
fs::path myPath = "../../somepath/morepath";
fs::canonical(myPath);
```

All I get is:

```
..\..\somepath\morepath
```

Am I doing something wrong or it just doesn't work?

Comment: You'll probably like it better when you use the return value of canonical().

Comment: Yes! Thank you but it still returns something like `c:\path\..\somepath\morepath`